# My dateFormatter.dateFromString method always returns nil iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update a label to say whether or not if today's date is earlier or later than a date that came from a date picker. Pretty simple I thought but I can't figure out why my dateFromString method always returns nil. Because of that, I can't move forward. Any help explaining why this is, is very much appreciated!

```
let dataString = expirationField.text!
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let expiringTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataString)  //my expiringTime variable here always returns nil
```

Any code here after I do with expiringTime doesn't work because it always returns nil. Please help! Here is where expirationField.text comes from:

```
// Expiration Field

@IBAction func expirationFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    expirationField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you creating a date picker inside a text field? You can try adding a print statement inside datePickerValueChanged() to see if the function is called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `dateStyle` property on the `dateFormatter`.

Comment: Wow that's it huh? Thanks! It works! I guess I figured since it was already getting its dateStyle formatted in its input method that I didn't need to do that again. Thanks again.